# what is the proper way to call snprintf?

Tags: c, printf

I would like to know what is the safe/simple/proper way to call snprintf ?

```
#define 1024

char cwdir[SIZE];address[SIZE]
int n=0;
....
...
snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%i", address, n);
```

gcc 8.3 shows

```
‘%i’ directive output may be truncated writing between 1 and 11 bytes into a region of size between 0 and 1023 [-Werror=format-truncation=]
  snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%i", address, n);
                                               ^~
prog.c:272:2: note: ‘snprintf’ output between 3 and 1036 bytes into a destination of size 1024
  snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%i", address, n);
```

Comment: It's telling you that `address/n` might be longer than `path`.

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @user253751   but it's not  !

Comment: @karism The compiler is telling you that it could be. What if address is 1023 bytes long?

Comment: Please post real code. What you have actually posted contains a lot of syntax errors as well as not containing enough information to answer the question

Comment: Where is `path` declared, and where is `cwdir` used?

Answer (score 0):

> what is the safe/simple/proper way to call snprintf ?

- *safe* - That depends on what you consider as safe. Your way is safe insofar as it has defined behavior.
- *simple* - Your way is certainly simple.
- *proper* - A proper way would be to dimension the array `path` so that even if the string `address` has the maximum possible length 1023 the whole output of *address*, slash and *n* fits into `path`, i. e. `char path[SIZE+1+11];`.